# JPA repository saves the wrong type of a field in my entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, h2

- DB: **H2**
- Spring, JPA

I have an entity called Message with a field which type is basically just a generic parent with an id:

```
public class Message {

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @NonNull
    List<GenericDTO> records;
}
```

GenericDTO:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance
public class GenericDTO {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    @JsonIgnore
    private int dto_id;

    public String toStringMessage(List<GenericDTO> records){
        return "";
    }
}
```

ChildDTO:

```
@Data
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ChildDTO extends GenericDTO{
  // some fields
}
```

**Now when I try to save my Message, the records field is saved as GenericDTO instead of ChildDTO.**

Is this issue related to H2?

[image]

Comment: You rlist is `GenericDTO` and not a list of `ChildDTO`. Hence for JPA it needs to store a `GenericDTO`.

Comment: @M.Deinum yes but JPA should be able to handle this type of polymorphism isn't it? I have other ```ChildDTO```s too, that is the reason for the ```GenericDTO```. When I save my ```Message``` the DTO I am saving is a ```ChildDTO``` not a ```GenericDTO```.

Comment: The collection needs to have the proper type as the type will be determined by that and in this case that is `GenericDTO`. Also shouldn't `GenericDTO` be `abstract` and a `@MappedSuperclass` instead of an `@Entity`?

Comment: @M.Deinum if I use  ```@MappedSuperClass``` I can't use ```GenericDTO``` in the ```@OneToMany```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was a bit tricky, `GenericDTO` and `ChildDTO` are in different projects and what happened is that the package in the project where ChildDTO present was not scanned so it was unknown for spring. Adding a package scan solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

By default jpa persists all entities of hierarchy in a single table containing columns for all possible fields of entities. That's why your children are saved to GENERICDTO table. To save entities of each class of your hierarchy to a separate table you need to specify inheritance strategy:

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
```

I recommend that you check out this article to get more information on the topic: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-inheritance